# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:959)

Tags: java, bytebuffer

The following Java code compiles, but there's an error at runtime:

```
# javac ByteBufTest.java
# java ByteBufTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:959)
    at ByteBufTest.<init>(ByteBufTest.java:12)
    at ByteBufTest.main(ByteBufTest.java:33)
#
```

Why does this happen?

Note：Next, I need to use mDirectBuffer in JNI, so I have to use the ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEST_BUFFER_SIZE) function。

`ByteBufTest.java`:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ByteBufTest {

    public static final int TEST_BUFFER_SIZE = 128;

    private ByteBuffer mDirectBuffer;

    public ByteBufTest() {
        mDirectBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEST_BUFFER_SIZE);
        byte[] buf = mDirectBuffer.array();
        buf[1]=100;
    }

    public void test() {

        printBuffer("nativeInitDirectBuffer",mDirectBuffer.array());

    }

    private void printBuffer( String tag, byte[] buffer ) {
        StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for( int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++ ) {
            sBuffer.append(buffer[i]);
            sBuffer.append(" ");    
        }
        //System.out.println(tag+sBuffer);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ByteBufTest item = new ByteBufTest();
        item.test(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour. The Javadoc states

> throws UnsupportedOperationException - If this buffer is not backed by an accessible array

You should try another approach or search for another implementation, e.g.

```
mDirectBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[TEST_BUFFER_SIZE]);
```

Comment: ，I need to use mDirectBuffer in JNI, so I have to use the ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEST_BUFFER_SIZE) function

Comment: For JDK，the array() method of byte buffer class returns a byte array (byte []) of the buffer’s contents. This is only valid for non-direct buffers. When used with direct buffers this method throws an exception: UnsupportedOperationException。

For android，the array() works ok。

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs at runtime if the resulting buffer is not backed by an accessible array. You can try allocate() method.

Comment: Your reply is incomplete, hasArray() exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should call [java.nio.ByteBuffer.hasArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#hasArray()) to ensure that [java.nio.ByteBuffer.array()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()) will succeed in order to write clean and portable code as stated in the Java API documentation:

> If this method returns true then the array and arrayOffset methods may safely be invoked

You can allocate a direct writable NIO byte buffer in your Java source code by calling [java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect(int)) as you already do and call [java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(byte%5B%5D)) to store the content of the buffer into an array, [this method is supported by Android too](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer#get(byte%5B%5D)). Keep in mind that **it's a relative operation that affects the position of the NIO buffer**.

Maybe another approach would consist in using the NIO buffer as is without doing any conversion but I'm not sure that it suits your needs.